# Breeze.js: How to write a query using json for "not in listvalues" where clause

Tags: sql-server, json, node.js, breeze, sequelize.js

I am using breeze.js on the client and breeze_sequel (breeze+sequelize) on my nodejs backend and every thing works fine. Now I'am not able to perform a query of this type:

```
select * from MyTable 
where Field1 = 'foo' and Field1 not in ('some_value1', 'some_value2')
```

From my javascript client this is the json where clause I am building and sending over the wire:

```
var where = {
            'and': [
                { 'Field1': { 'eq': 'foo'} },                    
                {
                    not: [
                           {
                            'Field2': { in: ['value1', 'value1'] }
                         }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
```

From the server console output, I can see that the "not" clause is not applied in my query. This is the query sent to the database:

```
SELECT * FROM MYTABLE WHERE
FIELD1 = 'foo' AND FIELD2 IN ('value1','value2')
```

I dived into the source code of the breeze_sequel library (especially the file SequelizeQuery.json.js ) to see how the library translate my predicates into actual sql "where clause" and I saw these comments on the method "applyNot(q1)" (line 724) which obviously applies the "not" clause to a query:

```
    // rules are:
  // not { a: 1}             -> { a: { ne: 1 }}
  // not { a: { gt: 1 }}    -> { a: { le: 1}}}
  // not { and: { a: 1, b: 2 } -> { or:  { a: { $ne: 1 }, b: { $ne 2 }}}
  // not { or  { a: 1, b: 2 } -> { and: [ a: { $ne: 1 }, b: { $ne 2 }]}
```

It looks to me like breeze_sequel does not support whereclause of the type " where xxx not in ( **list** ) ". Is it a missing feature or maybe I am doing some mistake? (I would like to avoid to write a special service on the server side to handle these kinds of query).

Thank you in adavance, especially to the guys from breeze.js. (kudos for this wonderful library)

Comment: Can you show capture the network traffic and show the query that actually went over the wire?

Comment: Thank for the answer. I can confirm that  "not" clause is successfully sent over the wire and it reaches the backend server. The problem is when breeze.js (server-side) translates this incoming json into a query with predicates, the "not" clause disappears from the generated query sent to sequelize.js